# How to determine a value in a column immediately before a value in another column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

## Plot

Following is a plot of speeds of two vehicles over time. The subject vehicle (blue) is following the lead vehicle (red) in the same lane. So, the speed profile of subject vehicle is very similar to lead vehicle's.

[image]

I have manually labelled the points where a vehicle changes its speed by acceleration/deceleration. Now, I want to determine these points from the data. Following are the sample data:

## Data

```
> dput(veh)
structure(list(Time = c(287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 
295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 
308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 
321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331), fit_p = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 8.86, 8.5, 8.15, 7.79, 7.44, 7.08, 6.73, 6.38, 6.1, 6.48, 
6.86, 7.24, 7.63, 8.01, 8.38, 8.58, 8.68, 8.7, 8.53, 8.33, 8.12, 
7.92, 7.71, 7.74, 8.1, 8.45, 8.8, 9.15, 9.29, 9.22, 9.16, 9.09, 
9.13, 9.25, 9.37, 9.49, 9.51, 9.34, 9.17, NA, NA, NA), psi_p2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 298, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 304, 305, NA, 307, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 313, NA, NA, NA, 317, 
NA, NA, NA, 321, NA, NA, NA, NA, 326, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), slo_p = c(-0.35, 
-0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, 
-0.35, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.2, 0.02, 0.02, -0.2, 
-0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, -0.06, 
-0.06, -0.06, -0.06, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17), fit_v = c(NA, NA, NA, 9.16, 8.57, 
7.99, 7.4, 7.23, 7.13, 7.04, 6.94, 6.85, 6.75, 6.66, 7.07, 7.57, 
8.06, 8.56, 9.04, 9.15, 9.26, 9.37, 9.15, 8.92, 8.68, 8.45, 8.22, 
7.99, 8.03, 8.24, 8.55, 8.87, 9.02, 8.96, 8.89, 8.82, 8.75, 8.99, 
9.28, 9.47, 9.42, 9.37, NA, NA, NA), psi_v2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 293, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 300, NA, NA, NA, NA, 305, 
NA, NA, 308, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 314, 315, 316, NA, NA, 319, 
NA, NA, NA, 323, NA, NA, 326, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), slo_v = c(-0.59, 
-0.59, -0.59, -0.59, -0.59, -0.59, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 
-0.1, -0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, -0.23, 
-0.23, -0.23, -0.23, -0.23, -0.23, 0.04, 0.16, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
-0.07, -0.07, -0.07, -0.07, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, 
-0.05, -0.05, -0.05)), .Names = c("Time", "fit_p", "psi_p2", 
"slo_p", "fit_v", "psi_v2", "slo_v"), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the column `psi_v2`, I have the time where subject vehicle changed the speed. These are all the `S` points. The points where the lead vehicle changed the speed are in the column `psi_p2`. But, I only want to determine the location of those points in `psi_p2` which happened immediately before point `S`. These points are all the `L` points on the plot. For instance, S1 happened at `psi_v2`=300, therefore, L1 is 298 in `psi_p2`.

## Question

I guess that I need to use `which()` to determine the relevant points from `psi_p2`. But I don't know how to code the part where only the "immediately before" point is picked.
Once the points are identified, I want to check if the subject vehicle accelerated in response to lead vehicle's acceleration. The acceleration of subject vehicle is in `slo_v` and that of lead vehicle is in`slo_p`. Example: For S1, slo_v = 0.5, and for L1, slo_p = 0.38. Since subject vehicle accelerated due to acceleration of lead vehicle, we call it "opening" (or "closing" in opposite case). 
So, my desired output is:

```
structure(list(Time = 287:331, fit_p = c(NA, NA, NA, 8.86, 8.5, 
8.15, 7.79, 7.44, 7.08, 6.73, 6.38, 6.1, 6.48, 6.86, 7.24, 7.63, 
8.01, 8.38, 8.58, 8.68, 8.7, 8.53, 8.33, 8.12, 7.92, 7.71, 7.74, 
8.1, 8.45, 8.8, 9.15, 9.29, 9.22, 9.16, 9.09, 9.13, 9.25, 9.37, 
9.49, 9.51, 9.34, 9.17, NA, NA, NA), psi_p2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 298L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 304L, 305L, 
NA, 307L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 313L, NA, NA, NA, 317L, NA, NA, 
NA, 321L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 326L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), slo_p = c(-0.35, 
-0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, 
-0.35, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.2, 0.02, 0.02, -0.2, 
-0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, -0.06, 
-0.06, -0.06, -0.06, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, -0.17, -0.17, 
-0.17, -0.17, -0.17, -0.17), fit_v = c(NA, NA, NA, 9.16, 8.57, 
7.99, 7.4, 7.23, 7.13, 7.04, 6.94, 6.85, 6.75, 6.66, 7.07, 7.57, 
8.06, 8.56, 9.04, 9.15, 9.26, 9.37, 9.15, 8.92, 8.68, 8.45, 8.22, 
7.99, 8.03, 8.24, 8.55, 8.87, 9.02, 8.96, 8.89, 8.82, 8.75, 8.99, 
9.28, 9.47, 9.42, 9.37, NA, NA, NA), psi_v2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 293L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 300L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 305L, 
NA, NA, 308L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 314L, 315L, 316L, NA, NA, 319L, 
NA, NA, NA, 323L, NA, NA, 326L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), slo_v = c(-0.59, 
-0.59, -0.59, -0.59, -0.59, -0.59, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 
-0.1, -0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, -0.23, 
-0.23, -0.23, -0.23, -0.23, -0.23, 0.04, 0.16, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 
-0.07, -0.07, -0.07, -0.07, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, 
-0.05, -0.05, -0.05), label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 
4L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 6L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 
1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "L1", 
"L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7&S7", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", 
"S5", "S6"), class = "factor"), condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "closing", 
"opening"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", "fit_p", "psi_p2", 
"slo_p", "fit_v", "psi_v2", "slo_v", "label", "condition"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-45L))
```

Kindly guide me what function should I use to identify these points? I prefer using `dplyr` because I have multiple pairs like this example. An operation for one data frame can then be used on all others using `group_by()`.

Comment: `dplyr` has a version of the `lag` and `lead` function. These allow you to retrieve values that are in rows before and after the current one. Check their help to see if they are of use for you.